# Associative php array sent via jquery returns [Object object]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have to pass a php multidimensional array via ajax/jQuery to another php file.
I have encoded the array using 
I expected theat every item in the array would have been an array itself. Instead it returns [Object object].
How can I access the data using php?

here's my code:

in the first php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr_data = <?php echo json_encode($itemsData); ?>;
$("#confirmButton").click(function(){
    $.post("send_test.php", {"my_array_data[]":my_array_data}, function( data ) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

the other php file:

```
<?php
$my_array_data = $_POST['my_array_data'];
?>
```

if I try to retrieve the first row (`$my_array_data[0]`) I get `[Object object]`
I just want to access to `$my_array_data[0]['category']` etc.

Comment: Use `json_decode()`.

Comment: you called your array arr_data but in your $.post you call it my_array_data

Comment: what exactly is in `$itemsData`? note that if you're using string-keys for that array, it WILL be forced into an object in JS - js arrays do not allow non-numeric (and non-sequential) keys.

Comment: `json_encode` will produce a JS object (`{}`) for associative arrays. Either cast it back to an array in 'the other php file', or access it using `$my_array_data[0]->category`.

Comment: Now if we could just get it all into one answer you'd be all set.

Comment: Stop using `alert` as a debugging tool, and this becomes a lot easier.

Comment: To back up what @adeneo is saying: [Quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of errors here:

- the data you are passing to ajax has an incorrect key using brackets`[]`
- you are not passing the correct object through ajax since `my_array_data` is never defined

redo your code like this:

**PHP**

```
$itemsData = array(
    array(
        "test" => 30,
        "test2" => 10,
    ),
    array(
        "test" => 90,
        "test2" => 50,
    )
);
```

**JS**

```
var arr_data = <?php echo json_encode($itemsData); ?>;
$("#confirmButton").click(function () {
    $.post("send_test.php", {my_array_data: arr_data}, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Then in **send_test.php**

```
$data = $_POST['my_array_data'];
print_r($data);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [test] => 30
            [test2] => 10
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [test] => 90
            [test2] => 50
        )

)
```

Comment: FYI, JSON would also be a valid javascript object when outputted without quotes. Also, PHP accepts keys ending with `[]`, and does something special with them, though not when passed like the OP does.

Comment: @adeneo can you please emphasize on this statement: _"JSON would also be a valid javascript object when outputted without quotes"_ I want to disagree but perhaps you are right. Can you please explain

Comment: It's called JavaScript Object Notation for a reason, it's valid javascript without the quotes, and is outputted exactly as an object, while putting it in quotes makes it a string.

Comment: oh I see your point now. Yes you are right, that is what JSON means, but can you  assign that to a JS variable and pass that through AJAX without making it a string first?

Comment: With jQuery you can, you're already passing an object, why wouldn't an object as the value of `my_array_data` be valid as well.

Comment: @adeneo I see what you mean now. I had to test it out. Thanks for pointing that out. I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you so much @CodeGodie and all of you guys. It worked like a breeze. The wrong array name is due to my typo here on StackOverflow. The problem was the bracketed array. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You're putting json-encoded data into the `arr_data` javascript variable - however you don't appear to be sending that to the other php file.

In the *other* php file, try using `json_decode` on the data you're receiving in the POST request:

```
$my_array_data = json_decode($_POST['my_array_data']);
```

Comment: He's not sending JSON in the `$.post` parameter, he doesn't need to decode it. JSON is just being used to generate a Javascript object/array literal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Aric says, name array consistently like this:

```
var my_arr_data = <?php echo json_encode($itemsData); ?>;
```